# docker Django runserver blocks binaries connecting to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I have a Django app running inside docker which use MySQL DB and it is working totally fine. I got several Python binaries which I need to run in docker while `./manage.py runserver` is running. But running binaries give me following error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'web'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES)")
```

The error is gone and my binaries work fine if I stop `./manage.py runserver`. I thought MySQL connections per user could be an issue so I ran.

```
GRANT USAGE on *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10;
```

But it did nothing and I am stuck with same behavior. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Try running `mysql -u <user> -p -h <mysql server>` on the command line and see if you can connect.

Comment: 127.17.0.3 is a client

Comment: Ok. replace that with the database server.

Comment: but just tried and it asked for password and then ```ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.3' (113)```

Comment: It's not a connection error AFAIK. I mean if it was connection error, ```./manage.py runserver``` may not have worked in the first place.

Comment: So that is  the problem. It looks like your user either does not exist, or does not have the right credentials to access the database. Try creating a new user : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: Just tried dropping that user and recreating with mentioned url. Same error.

Comment: Ok.. If you are using windows, you may have to logout and log back in. Another thing, on fresh installs of mysql, there is a `root` user that is created by default. So, `mysql -u root <other credentials>` should work (To test everything is setup properly). This is not recommended to be used in your project setup though.

Comment: Not Windows but Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Yes root is working fine. I never use root in apps.

Comment: I dont know what else to recommend. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <databasename>.* TO '<username>'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: deleted user and recreated and granted all privileges with grant option WORKED! Although I have done it before but not by removing user completely. thanks for you help!